# kotlin class on any class

Tags: android, class, kotlin

I'm trying to store class type as a member variable in my android application, so that I can go to that activity next.
I am using `Class of Any`, but I don't know why it is not accepting type of any class, which means anything.

```
    val state : MutableLiveData<Pair<State,Class<Any>>>
            = MutableLiveData(Pair(State.Initial,MainActivity::class.java))
```

Can anyone help me resolving this issue ?

Comment: Use `Class<out Any>`. This will say Class<MainActivity> is subtype od Class<Any> so will be assignable. Previously types were invariant, i.e. there was no relation between Class<MainActivity> and Class<Any>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `out` modifier for generic type:

```
val state : MutableLiveData<Pair<State, Class<out Any>>>
        = MutableLiveData(Pair(State.Initial, MainActivity::class.java))
```

`out` modifier is used in Kotlin to indicate covariance (similar to `? extends T` in Java).